# Enable to create docker repository in centos 8

Tags: docker

I'm working on Centos 8 VM. I want to install docker in this machine.

As per guidelines in below link trying to Adding Docker CE Official Package Repository
https://linuxhint.com/install_docker_ce_centos8/

Getting timeout after sometime. Not able to access this website https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with internet or proxy, I don't think it's related to docker.

Comment: I'm able to install all other package in VM